# Детский вопрос: уключина и ключ ― это родственные слова?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, однокоренные-слова, морфемный-разбор

Разбирали с ребёнком примеры омонимов, добрались до слова **ключ**.
Подбирали однокоренные слова: ключница, ключик, выключатель, **уключина**…

Остановилась и задумалась...
В [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) обнаружила (по Тихонову):
уклю́чина ― корень **-уключин-**; окончание **-а**.

Возникли вопросы:
Как и когда возникло слово *уключина*? Родственно ли оно слову *ключ*?
Какие есть ещё однокоренные слова к *уключине*?
[Посмотрели: в печатном варианте словообразовательного словаря А. Н. Тихонова (1990 год) слово "уключина" отсутствует.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уключина — суффиксально-префиксальное производное слова *ключ* (см., напр., словарь А. И. Кузнецовой и Т. Ф. Ефремовой). Оно существовало уже в середине XVIII века:

> На краях судна, наподобие скоб или положенной цепи, сделаны были уключины, осыпанные голубыми прозрачными каменьями; веслы вызолочены, и гребцы ― в лазоревых одеждах. [М. Д. Чулков. Пересмешник, или Славенские сказки (1766-1768)] [НКРЯ](http://ruscorpora.ru/search-main.html#)

В этом слове, видимо, отражена идея включения: уключина как бы вмещает, включает в себя весло.

Однокоренных слов — множество: приключение, включить, переключатель, злоключение...

Comment: Извините, открыла Вашу ссылку и... Каким образом в ней что-то можно посмотреть?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова это ссылка на источник, а не на какой-либо материал. Корпус просит давать ее, когда цитируешь.